# If complex roots can be repeated, then can't an odd degree polynomial to have all complex roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

I learnt that an odd degree polynomial has at least one real root since complex roots occur in conjugate pair, but if complex roots can be repeated, then isn't it possible for an odd degree polynomial to have all complex roots? For example, a 5 degree polynomial can have 2 pairs of complex numbers and then one of the four can be repeated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A polynomial **with real coefficients** will have the same multiplicity for a root and its conjugate. It's true that a precise argument is needed to deal with the possibility that the roots have multiplicity larger than $1$.

Comment: A monic odd-degree polynomial in $x$ diverges to $\pm\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, so [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) implies it has a real root.

Comment: You seem to be asking about whether odd-degree polynomials **over the reals** can have roots **that are all non-real**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of a polynomial $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with all coefficients being real numbers:

For each complex root, $a+bi$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, its **complex conjugate**, $a - bi$, will be a root of $f$, too.

If you have a repeated complex root, then its complex conjugate will be repeated, too. For example, if you have a repeated root at $i$, which could arise from a factor of $(x^2 + 1)^2$, then you will have a repeated root at $-i$, too. Since all complex roots – including those that repeat – come in pairs, having an odd degree will be achievable only if there is at least one real root.

In your example of a degree five polynomial with two pairs of complex numbers, i.e., two pairs of roots with their complex conjugates, $\{a+bi, a-bi\}$ and $\{c + di,  c - di\}$, there cannot be a distinct fifth complex root – it would need its conjugate to appear. Similarly, you cannot have a fifth root that repeats one of the previous four, as this would, again, require its complex conjugate to appear another time (resulting in a degree that is more than five).

Comment: Did you mean in the context of polynomials with real coefficients? Clearly $f = x-i$ is a polynomial $\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ for which $i$ is a root, but its complex conjugate isn't a root.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Yes, I will update to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you! @BenjaminDickman

Answer (score 3):

An odd degree polynomial **with real coefficients** must have at least one real root.  This is because in such a case, each complex root, with or without multiplicity, will have a corresponding complex conjugate root.  That is to say, if $r$ is a complex root of the polynomial $f(z)$ where $\deg f = n$, then $\bar r$ will also be a root, since $$\bar r^k = \overline{r^k}$$ for every nonnegative integer $k$ implies

$$f(\bar r) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \bar r^k = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \overline{(r^k)} \overset{\Im(a_k) = 0}{=} \overline{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k r^k} = \overline{f(r)} = \bar 0 = 0.$$  It is the step from the third to the fourth expression that requires that the coefficients $a_k$ have zero imaginary component.  This is true whether or not $n$ is even or odd.  But by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, every polynomial (with or without real coefficients) will have exactly $n$ roots, counting multiplicity.  So for a polynomial of odd degree, all complex coefficients occur in complex conjugate pairs, which leaves at least one unpaired real root.

It is easy to construct an example of a polynomial of odd degree with complex coefficients for which all roots are complex; e.g.,

$$f(z) = (z - 1+i)(z - 1-i)(z - i) = z^3 - (2+i)z^2 + (2+2i)z - 2i.$$

Comment: Easier polynomial of odd degree with only complex roots: $z - i$

Answer (score 0):

Note that a polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbf{R}[x]$ of odd degree has negative values if we take $x$ small enough, that is let $x \to -\infty$ then $p \to -\infty$ because the first term will eventually outcompete the others. And for $x \to \infty$ the same goes, namely that $p \to \infty$. Because polynomials are continuous you know that there has to be a real root. So it is not possible for a polynomial of odd degree to have only complex roots.